# Prevent Json ordering while inserting into Mysql table

Tags: mysql, json

The reordering of Json-Content is already an known issue while sending AJAX Request, but I wasn't aware that the same happens while inserting Json-content into an Mysql Table with JSON type.

In this case the mysql server also orders its content before saving.

before:

```
{"c":3, "b":2, "a":1}
```

after:

```
{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}
```

Suppose I would like to prevent this ordering for some purpose... Is there any possibility to disable the ordering without adapting the Json data itself?

Comment: What do you mean by *json ordering*? Please provide a few examples of what you are seeing.

Comment: JSON datatype is stored in some internal format, so back reconstruction may reorder its components. The only way to avoid this is in store JSON in a field of string type.

Comment: @Akina, storing json in string is non of our options, as we are using the mysql json function to query the data.

Comment: Please see this question, I think it's same with your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382457/mysql-json-column-change-array-order-after-saving

Comment: @Widada, you right. but seems to be unanswered yet. just to contact 3rd party is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Nevertheless - either string datatype and storing order (which makes no sense except the positional order of array elements) or JSON datatype and possible reordering. *we are using the mysql json function to query the data.* JSON functions may easily accept string datatype arguments if they're valid JSON values.

Comment: @ChristianFelix: the ordering of key/value pairs in a json object is not meaningful - these are basically unordered, so your database, as well as your web server, are free to change it. Why do you specifically want to preserve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to this is to serialize this > then store it > retrieve > then parse

For example:
First store object as a string

```
var jsonDataStringed = JSON.stringify(myJsonData);
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(id,jsonDataStringed);
```

then to retrieve the string and change it back to object

```
db.sequelize.query(`SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE`);
var myJsonData = JSON.parse(db[0])
```