# Mysql Rows which have same values but in different column & Show them in a single row

Tags: mysql, json, group-by, left-join, where-clause

What I want to do is merge the rows which have same values but in different column & Show them in a single row

I Tried to use the JSON_ARRAYAGG() but didn't get the results in my way

**User Data**

Here secondary user is the reference of primary_user

| id | username | secondary_user | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | max_max | null | 1356 |
| 2 | jac_jac | 1 | 1111 |
| 3 | leo_leo | null | 2222 |
| 4 | bob_bob | 3 | 4444 |

**Result I want**

| id | username | secondary_user | code | secondary_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | max_max | null | 1356 | [{"jac_jac", "1111"}] |
| 3 | leo_leo | null | 2222 | [{"bob_bob", "4444"}] |

Comment: #1. What is precise MySQL version? #2. Imagine that there is two more users `id=5` and  `id=6` whose secondary user is `secondary_user=2`. What is desired output in this case?

Comment: "Imagine that there is two more users id=5 and id=6 whose secondary user is secondary_user=2". We dont consider as if it's already a secondary user. Mysql 2.18.1

Comment: #1. What is precise MySQL version? #2. Your output value `[{"jac_jac", "1111"}]` is not valid JSON... do you need string output of this pattern?

Comment: MySQL 2.18.1. Out should be in this way  [{username :"jac_jac", code : "1111"}]

Comment: *MySQL 2.18.1.* Not exists. Execute `SELECT VERSION();` and provide complete output.

Comment: MySQL 5.7.33-log

Comment: If so then the answer provided by @forpas is useful. Apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a self join of the table.
Then use `JSON_OBJECT()` to create valid json objects for a user in the form of `{"user_name": "user_code"}` and not `{"user_name", "user_code"}` and finally aggregate and use `JSON_ARRAYAGG()`:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT(t2.username, t2.code)) secondary_users
FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.secondary_user = t1.id
WHERE t1.secondary_user IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

I assume that `id` is the primary key of the table.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c833fc19b4e9e986d1a01b243b7483fc).

Comment: what would i do if need secondary user in this way [{username :"jac_jac", code : "1111"}]? Also thanks for you help it working.

Comment: @AkhilRana for this output there is a known problem in MySql which you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05100436fee518884830e66c18a9c15d Mysql changes the order of the items. This has been discussed in other questions in SO like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48382457/mysql-json-column-change-array-order-after-saving

Comment: JSON_OBJECT(t2.username, t2.code) in demo it working fine but in workbench it throwing error "JSON documents may not contain null member names mysql". Why?

Comment: @AkhilRana why? Is username nullable? If it is then what result do you want for this case?